# mod_proxy/mod_proxy_ajp logging

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I'm trying to log mod_proxy requests to separate logs to identify that its forwarding requests to which tomcat server.

*VirtualHost Configuration:*

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
<Proxy balancer://appcluster>
        BalancerMember ajp://192.168.1.1:8009/ route=tomcat01 keepalive=on retry=300 ttl=30
        BalancerMember ajp://192.168.1.2:8009/ route=tomcat01 keepalive=on retry=300 ttl=30
</Proxy>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName xyz.abc.com
 DocumentRoot /www
 ErrorLog logs/app_stg-error_log
 TransferLog logs/app_stg-access_log
 ProxyPass / balancer://appcluster/app_stg/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
 ProxyPassReverse / balancer://appcluster/app_stg/
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to log on which Balancer Member my request has been forwarded.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: I want to log on which Balancer Member my request has been forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

Its achived by adding below LogFormat.

```
LogFormat "%h \"%{BALANCER_WORKER_NAME}e\" %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" custom
```

You can add this format to httpd.conf or in Virtual Host.

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
<Proxy balancer://appcluster>
        BalancerMember ajp://192.168.1.1:8009/ route=tomcat01 keepalive=on retry=300 ttl=30
        BalancerMember ajp://192.168.1.2:8009/ route=tomcat01 keepalive=on retry=300 ttl=30
</Proxy>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName xyz.abc.com
 DocumentRoot /www
 LogFormat "%h \"%{BALANCER_WORKER_NAME}e\" %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" custom
 ErrorLog logs/app_stg-error_log
 CustomLog logs/app_stg-access_log custom
 ProxyPass / balancer://appcluster/app_stg/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
 ProxyPassReverse / balancer://appcluster/app_stg/
</VirtualHost>
```

Log File Snippet:

```
2xx.1xx.1xx.1xx "ajp://10.220.102.94:8009/" - [13/Jan/2013:08:36:54 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17"
```